# How do Print Hindi Text On Itext Pdf Report using Java From Database?

Tags: java, unicode, printing, javafx-2, itext

I am using itext liberary for pdf generation in mine JavaFX project.Now i want's to print hindi , punjabi text from database inside report , How can i do this. However IText library is not recognise hindi and punjabi unicode ???
here is mine code

```
            out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        // initialize document with page size and margins
        document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60, 40, 60, 60);
        this.setAlignmentOfCompanyInfo(Common.comp
                .getReportsHeaderAlignment());
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);

        writer.setPageEvent(new PageEventForAddressBookReport());
        document.open();PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
            PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate(w, h);
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Graphics2D g2 = tp.createGraphicsShapes(w, h);        
            g2.drawString("वर्तमान शेष", 200, 100);                
            g2.dispose();
            g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            cb.addTemplate(tp, 50, 400);
           BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(100, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
           Graphics2D ig2 = bi.createGraphics();
           ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("ourImageName.PNG"));
           Image image = Image.getInstance(tp);
           document.add(new Chunk(image,5,5));
document.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am using hindi text to be appear in PDf as below

```
        BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont("/home/mani/Documents/Back up (works)/Devanagari/Devanagari.ttf", 
        BaseFont.COURIER,    BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font=new Font(unicode,12,Font.NORMAL,new BaseColor(50,205,50));

        table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 10, 60, 30 });
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPCell customerLblCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("karent balance",
                font));
```

Its working fine in mine case .

Comment: ExceptionConverter: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: Courier

Comment: Can i have the more detailed trace plz ?

Comment: BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont("assets/fonts/devanagari.ttf",
                    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

 Font   catFont=new Font(unicode,16,Font.NORMAL,new BaseColor(50,205,50));

Comment: By using this nothing write on pdf file in hindi .

Answer (score 1):

As `itext` is not supporting vernacular language, convert text to bitmap and set as image. Use below method for conversion:

```
public Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, float stroke,
        int color) {

    TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    // paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(color);
    // paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(20f);

    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
    float baseline = (int) (-paint.ascent() + 3f); // ascent() is negative

    StaticLayout staticLayout = new StaticLayout(text, 0, text.length(),
            paint, 435, android.text.Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f,
            1.0f, false);

    // int linecount = staticLayout.getLineCount();
    //
    // int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 3) * linecount + 10;

    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(staticLayout.getWidth(),
            staticLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    // canvas.drawARGB(100, 100, 100, 100);

    staticLayout.draw(canvas);

    return image;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to add the text in a notation that isn't Unicode, but that's not the main problem. The main problem is that you aren't providing the right font. You need a font that knows how to draw Indic glyphs. Arial Unicode MS is such a font:

```
String text = "\u0936\u093e\u0902\u0924\u093f";
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate(100, 50);
Graphics2D g2 = tp.createGraphicsShapes(100, 50);
java.awt.Font font = new java.awt.Font(
    "Arial Unicode MS", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 12);
g2.setFont(font);
g2.drawString("Graphics2D: " + text, 0, 40);
g2.dispose();
cb.addTemplate(tp, 36, 750);
```

Note that this assumes that Java has access to the font `arialuni.ttf`.

Comment: i had already found this example as an alternative, but i am looking for something similar to below                                                           document.add(new Paragraph("text",font)); but paragaraph does not accepts awt fonts.

Comment: is there any alternative to make own custome font(.ttf) and use it inside BaseFont method ?

Comment: Hindi isn't supported in iText except in the way described in my answer. We are currently writing broader Hindi support, but we probably won't open source that part as it's commercially interesting given the demand for it.

Comment: I am using this istead of hindi fontBaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont("/home/mani/Documents/Back up (works)/Devanagari/Devanagari.ttf", 
      BaseFont.COURIER,    BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
   Font unii=new Font(unicode,12,Font.NORMAL,new BaseColor(50,205,50));
      Font font1003=new Font(un,12,Font.NORMAL,new BaseColor(50,205,50));
   table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 10, 60, 30 });
   table.setWidthPercentage(100);
   PdfPCell customerLblCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("karent balance",
     unii));

Comment: i just tried to run ParseHtml8 but it shows error on    XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
        fontProvider.register("resources/fonts/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf");
        CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory()); @Bruno Lowagie